# Pass field name in dapper query

Tags: c#, dapper

I'm creating a function where I check if a maintenance day is checked in the database. Each Column is Maintenance + DayName (MaintenanceSunday, MaintenanceMonday, etc.).

It appears that anytime you pass in an object, it wants to take the value of what is being checked and not "inject" the string. Is there a way to safely achieve this (ie not String.Format("where {0} = ...", field))? I really don't want to open up the possibility of SQL Injection here (though there is an earlier check to see if q.ToUpper() is in a list of "SUNDAY", "MONDAY", etc. so I guess there's that safeguard)

I attempted this, but it bombs attempting to compare 'Maintenancesunday' to true (bit):

```
string field = "Maintenance" + q; // q = "sunday"
return conn.Query<Data>("SELECT * FROM Data WHERE @Field = @Value", new { Field = field, Value = true }).ToList();
```

Comment: your query doesn't look right, you're comparing parameter values against eachother rather than columns

Comment: fair point. is There a way in Dapper to safely pass in a column name where I'm attempting with Field?

Comment: Not really, your query should look like this:
`conn.Query<Data>("SELECT * FROM Data WHERE Field = @Field AND Value = @Value", new { Field = field, Value = true })` for example. This parameterizes your  query and is safe from sql-injection

Comment: Unless I'm reading it wrong, that'd be more for an attribute-value built table, right?

Comment: You might be able to use `Dapper-Extensions` for what you want: https://github.com/tmsmith/Dapper-Extensions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dapper just uses ADO.NET, which doesn't support parameterized column names. I guess you need some hard-coding to accomplish this.

Comment: `Dapper-Extensions` appears to be able to build predicates without using hard-coded column names

Comment: @Ric yes, but than you'll have to create properties for every maintenance day on your POCO.

Comment: You're right, I don't see anything built in that allows for it. Dapper-Extensions may allow for a method of doing it, but I want to minimize the amount of dependencies where possible. Basically, since I'm only looking for a day, I moved the check to the beginning that if the string in upper case doesn't match a day (in upper case) with a giant comment of removing the check (tuning is okay) opens it up for SQL Injection, return out and just do a String.Format to put it in.